# Adwords api to fetch keywords associated with a google adwords account who can authoritize my app to get his google tracking id etc

Tags: google-ads-api

I am a telephony based company. I would like my users to authenticate me using OAuth method to fetch their google adwords campaign details related to the google account. Which google adwords api should be used to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by campaign details? There are many kinds of campaign-level report API that gives information about campaign like this performance report, for example: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report